# How to get value from latitude and longitude to create google maps marker in script?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input text in HTML and need to pass coordinates to make a `marker` in Google maps.

jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=r3M9Kp7ff7

How to pass it from HTML to a JavaScript with good type of data?

```
<label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
<input id="latitude" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.department.latitude" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Latitude" value=""/>
<label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
<input id="longitude" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.department.longitude" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Longitude" value=""/>
<label for="map">Pozycja na mapie</label>
<div id="map">
<script>
function initMap() {
  var myLat = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
  var myLng = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 51.75, lng: 19.46},
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position:{myLat, myLng}, // not working
                 map:map,
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [JSFiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.com) so that we can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script Try This One

```
 <script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLat = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        var myLng = document.getElementById('longitude').value;

        var myCenter = {lat: myLat, lng: myLng};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: myCenter
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myCenter,
          map: map
        });

      }
    </script>
```

Marker position syntax should be
position: {lat: myLat, lng: myLng}
instead of this
position:{myLat, myLng},